# Rust alpha 1 - base64 not found

Tags: rust

A newest version of Rust:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (6c065fc8c 2015-02-17) (built 2015-02-18)
```

According to [the documentation](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.0al/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/serialize/base64/trait.ToBase64.html) this should compile (and it compiled before):

```
use serialize::base64;
use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, FromBase64};
```

But it says

```
src/lib.rs:6:5: 6:22 error: unresolved import `serialize::base64`. There is no `base64` in `serialize`
src/lib.rs:6 use serialize::base64;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:7:25: 7:33 error: unresolved import `serialize::base64::ToBase64`. Could not find `base64` in `serialize`
src/lib.rs:7 use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, FromBase64};
                                     ^~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:7:35: 7:45 error: unresolved import `serialize::base64::FromBase64`. Could not find `base64` in `serialize`
src/lib.rs:7 use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, FromBase64};
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Comment: That isn't the official documentation, that's at http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/. Anyway, you should take a look at the [release notes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md) and see if it mentioned there.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, where is it then? In the release notes it doesn't say it's been moved somewhere.

Comment: No stability promises were made. Rust is still a moving target in its 1.0-alpha phase. See http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/02/13/Final-1.0-timeline.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the nightlies, and so should refer to the [nightlies documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html).

The `serialize` crate as been moved to [an external repository on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-serialize) to use it, simply insert

```
[dependencies]
rustc-serialize = "0.2"
```

in you `Cargo.toml` and import the crate in your rust code with:

```
extern crate "rustc-serialize" as rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::base64;
```

You should also change your `#[derive(Encodable)]` and `#[derive(Decodable)]` to `#[derive(RustcEncodable)]` and `#[derive(RustcDecodable)]`